# Types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, type-inference, inferred-type

I'm kind of new in Haskell and I have difficulty understanding how inferred types and such works.

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
(.) :: (a -> b) -> (c -> a) -> c -> b
```

What EXACTLY does that mean?

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldl :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a
foldl1 :: (a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> a
```

What are the differences between these?

And the inferred type of

`foldr map` is `[a] -> [a -> a] -> [a]`

But why is it that?

THANKS!

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of currying?

Comment: I believe it is the concept of making multi argument functions into taking only 1 argument. something like f (x,y) = (f y) o (g x)?

Comment: You can find out the type of something with the :t command in ghci (interactive haskell shell):

    >> :t foldr map
    foldr map :: [b] -> [b -> b] -> [b]

Comment: What do you mean by "how would I define the inferred type of something ..."? If you declare the type of something, it does not need to be inferred.

Comment: By the way, it's considered good form on Stack Overflow to accept answers that give a correct solution. You've asked six questions so far, but accepted no answers.

Comment: @camccann thanks for the advice. I did not know that. I'll do that now

Comment: It also has the positive effect of people WANTING to help you, when they have the chance to get a piece of that cake :)

Comment: You guys all answered most of my questions very well, thanks! 

I guess my only concern is that something like 

>:t foldr map
foldr map :: [a] -> [a -> a] -> [a]

How can I determine [a] -> [a -> a] -> [a] myself (like on paper)?

I've edited the question for clarity.

Comment: @Linda: I've edited my answer, have a look at the very bottom (god, it has become big)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you take the example of

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

This means that map takes 2 arguments

1. A function from type a to type b
2. A list of type a

And it returns

1. A list of b

You can already see the pattern here, but it'll be clearer when we substitute 'a' and 'b'

- a = String
- b = Int

So this type definiton will be

```
map :: (String -> Int) -> [String] -> [Int]
```

so now it's a function that takes a String and returns and Int, and a list of Strings and returns a list of Ints.

Say our function that takes a String and returns and Int is `read`. `read` uses the string you give it to convert it to something different. Because we put it into an Int context here, it will convert the string to int

```
map read ["1", "2", "112", 333"]
```

This will result in

```
[1, 2, 112, 333]
```

because `map` takes your function `read` and *maps* (applies) it to every element of the list. You don't have to TELL `read` it's argument like `read "1"`, or `read n`, because `map` takes care of that for you.

And that's really all there is to it. The type of a function only says which types it takes and what type it returns. Of course, there's also currying, but you'll get to that later either on purpose or not! It basically means, that a function does not take *many* arguments, but only **one.** Say you take the function `+`. If you evaluate `1+2`, it returns a function which takes another number which is added to `1`, and because there IS another number here, `2`, it will use that. You could have evaluated it as `(1+)` and pass it on, possibly added the number some time later. It is clearer when you don't have the infix syntax of `+`. It could have been written `(+) 1 2`, so first this statement becomes `(+) 1` , which is of type (simplified! I won't introduce the Num typeclass here) `Int -> Int`. So `(+) 1` (or `(1+)` for that matter) is just ANOTHER function you can apply a value to, at which point the result will be able to calculate to 3.

Here's how this looks in practice: (Ignore the `(Num a) =>` part here if it confuses you, it's a concept you will later learn more about. Just replace the `a` types here with `Int` if you want, and ignore the `(Num a) =>` part completly.)

```
 (+)  :: (Num a) => a -> a -> a
 (+2) :: (Num a) => a -> a
(1+)  :: (Num a) => a -> a
(1+2) :: (Num a) => a

Prelude> (+2) 5
7
Prelude> map (+3) [1,2,3]
[4,5,6]
```

And to your second question: you don't define inferred types AT ALL. They are called "inferred", because the compiler/interpreter "infers" (read: computes) the types itself, without you explicitly naming them.

About the `foldX` differences: They all do the exact same thing: reduce a list to a single value. The difference between the functions is merely the internal definition. `foldl` folds the list from the left, and `foldr` does it to the right.

So to sum up a list, you can use all of them like this...

```
foldl1 (+) [1,2,3] == 6
foldr (+) 0 [1,2,3] == 6
foldl (+) 0 [1,2,3] == 6
```

You see, except for foldl1, you supply a function to fold, a starting value (accumulator) and a list to fold. `fold1` has it's own accumulator, you don't give it your own.

In practice, you should better use `foldr`, because unlike `fold` it's suitable for BIG lists without crashing due to a stack overflow (tee, hee). And exception to this rule is `foldl'` (notice the "'"!) in `Data.Map` - it's a strict fold that is also suitable for big lists.

If you want to give functions their types yourself (if you wrote them), consider this example:

```
double :: Int -> Int
double n = 2 * n
```

Or in a haskellish way

```
double :: Int -> Int
double = (*2)
```

The first line of both the examples (`double :: Int -> Int`) is what you're looking for. It's how you can force the compiler or interpreter to identify the function - you can omit then, and the compiler/interpreter will find them out (and sometimes even in a better way than one would first think of)

Answer (score 3):

Functions in Haskell use a notation called currying. A definition like

```
plus :: Int -> Int -> Int
```

means that `plus` is a function that takes two `Int`s and returns a value of the the rightmost type (which is `Int` again). More into detail, currying means you work with partially applied functions which allows you to write code like

```
plus1 :: Int -> Int
plus1 = plus 1
```

---

Lowercase identifiers in type signatures indicate a so called *type variable* that can be thought as a place-holder for any possible type.

The definition

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

therefore means *For any types `a` and `b`, `map` takes a function from `a` to `b` and a list of `a`'s, from which it produces a list of `b`'s*.

Let's take an example

```
map show [1, 2, 3]
```

We see, the given list is a list of `Int`'s, so `a = Int`. Furthermore, `map` should apply `show` to each element, which returns a `String`. Since `show` has to fit the type `a -> b` from the definition, we can deduce that `b = String`.

Our expression returns a `[b]`, so the result is a `[String]`.

To make such signatures even clearer, we can write it using a more verbose syntax

```
map :: forall a b . (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

This now explicitly states `map` is supposed to work with all types `a` and `b`.

---

For the folds, take a look on their [definitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher_order_function%29). Given above knowledge, the type signatures should be self-explaining when it's clear *what* the functions are supposed to do.

Example: `factorial n = foldl (*) 1 [1..n]`

The signature of `foldr map` becomes.

```
foldr map :: [a] -> [a -> a] -> [a]
```

You can also obtain these by simply typing `:t foldr map` into the Haskell interpreter (GHCi).

Answer (score 1):

In Haskell, a lower case variable is a type variable. Whereas `Char` just means `Char`, `a` or `b` could mean `Char`, or `Bool` or `Integer`, or some other type. The key is, all `a`s will be the same type. And all `b`s will be the same type.

For example, `map` takes as its first argument a function which takes one variable of type `a` and returns another of type `b`. Then `map` returns a new function which takes a list of type `a`. This new function returns a list of type `b`.

Suppose you had a function `increment` which added one to an integer. `map increment [1,2,3]` would ultimately return a list [2,3,4].

The earlier definition of `map` with the type variables replaced would look like:

`map :: increment -> [1,2,3] -> [2,3,4]`

and `increment`, BTW, would look like

`increment :: Integer -> Integer`

The reason it is written funny is because you can partially apply functions. Here I'll make a new function based on the partial applicaiton of map:

```
incrementList = map increment
```

Then you could use

```
incrementList [1,2,3]
```

which would produce the same result

Answer (score 1):

The lowercase letters in the type declarations are **type variables**. This means that when there is an `a` this must be the same type.

Bracketed (eg `(a -> b)`) subexpressions tend to mean that the function accepts a function as one of its parametres.

Rectangular brackets indicate a list of something.

So `map` accepts these arguments:

- `(a -> b)` a function that accepts one argument
- `[a]` a list that the first argument function can act on

and produces `[b]` a list as a result.

We can decode `(.)` the same way:

- `(a -> b)` is a function that accepts a single argument
- `(c -> a)` is a function that produces the same typa as the argument to the first function
- `c` an argument of the same type that the second function uses

However Haskell can do a neat thing and that is if you omit an argument it returns a function that has the remaining signature. So `(.)` is commonly used to chain functions.

Let's say we have 2 functions `ord :: Char -> Int` which takes a character and returns it's integer representation and `add32 :: Int -> Int` that adds 32 to it's argument.

When we write `upcaseVal = add32 . ord` the function upcaseVal now has the signature `upcaseVal :: Char -> Int` because the `(.)` function would have left it with `c -> b` and we substitue thes in the function definition.

So `foldr map` would have to be like this:

1. `foldr`'s first argument is a function that takes 2 arguments which `map` is.
2. Since the functions output has to be of the same type as the second argument (`(a -> b -> b`) we see that in `map` `a = b`

Thus the final type will be:

```
(b -> b) -> [b] -> [b] -> b -> [b] -> b
```

But I guess that doesn't have to bother you that much since the compiler deals with stuff like this most of the time.

Comment: Though I might have gotten confused with the `foldr map` type - take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: The type of `foldr map` is `[b] -> [b -> b] -> [b]`